# How to make cross reference on Enterprise achitect template editor?

Tags: uml, use-case, enterprise-architect

I am doing some use case specification on enterprise architect. When i was writting these documents on Word 2010, i used cross reference(hyperlinks) to show business rules that were on the other side of the document without making the reader scroll down the document. I really wanna know if enterprise architec have these features or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

In the template editor, you can insert hyperlinks by right-clicking into the template and choosign insert->hyperlink. But that's for URLs.

In your diagrams, you can create hyperlink elements that refer to other objects. But these are not active in the RTF/PDF output.

However, if you create hyperlinks in the notes of an element, these will be functional in a PDF report.

The [user guide](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/reporting/documentingprojects.html) or the [EA forum](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi) may offer further help.

If you ask questions like this one, please describe which version you operate with, your OS and what you have tried already to solve your problem.